# Performance of pointers vs index

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I have a std::vector of objects with n elements. Some of these elements I want to store in a doubly linked list. Is it faster(with respect to insertion/deletion of a object) to store for each object pointers to the next and to the previous object or is it faster to store the index of the next and previous object?

Comment: Does it even matter? And if so, why haven't you measured the difference?

Comment: Don't bother using a list at all, start with a vector and measure,  vector usually outperforms list even when testing the so called strong points of a list like lots of insertions and deletions

Comment: I am not using std::list. I have a vector and I am writing the linked list myself. The question is if I should do it with pointers or with indices.

Comment: compillers generate same asm code for both syntaxes: `p += 5; *p=x;` and `p[5]=x;`

Comment: Indices should be safer, because pointers may becomes invalid when the vector's location changes (due to some resizing). From the point of view of speed there shouln't be big difference, and remember, correctness has higher priority than micro-optimization of speed.

Comment: I usually prefer index to pointer. because 32-bit integer is usually enough for index but pointer can be 64-bit.

Comment: If you are making a linked list, you do not need a vector at all. You should use one or the other, otherwise you're wasting memory.

Comment: @andrew i know. I need the vector for other purposes